# Interface Segregation Principle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-principles, interface-segregation-principle

Anyone able to give a good illustration of how this works in jQuery?

Specifically with regards to the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988/the-interface-segregation-principle).

It sounds the same as Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) for OOP? How is it different?

Comment: I love jQuery but honestly I don't think it does a "good job" of handling Interface Segregation. Do you want points to the counter?

Comment: @Shakakai don't really think your comment helped me understand anything with regards to the question.

Comment: I wasn't trying to help you understand with that comment - merely asking would you accept a response that explains how jQuery doesn't follow the Interface Segregation Principle.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't really understand what you meant by counter... as in contrary... yes pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel more comfortable with answering my own question now.

With **Single Responsibility Principle**, I'm thinking mainly of objects created like in a game. That object should be responsible only for itself, in terms of internal functions/methods.

As for **Interface Segregation**, I'm thinking more of avoiding anonymous function calls, and segregating a large chunk of code... to different named calls. This was well explained by Paul Irish in jQuery Anti-Patterns for performance.

Instead of anonymous functions bound everywhere like

```
$(function() {
    //do stuff related to setup menu
    //add facebook, twitter widgets
    //more anonymous actions....
}):
```

Segregation into a well defined interface might look something like the below:

```
var homepage = (function() {
    function setupMenu() {
        //do stuff related to setup menu
    }
    function setupSocial() {
        //add facebook, twitter widgets
    }
    return {
        setupMenu:setupMenu,
        setupSocial:setupSocial
    }   
})();

$(function() {
    homepage.setupMenu();
    homepage.setupSocial();
})
```