# Does exposing some methods of a class through an Interface break any SOLID design principle?

Tags: c#, oop

I understand interface segregation and single responsibility principles guide against a class implementing methods or property it doesn't need. However, for the scenario described below where I have a User service with Login and Register methods, my Login Controller needs access to a single method (the login method). I have tried to hide the Register method by injecting a UserService object exposed through the ILogin interface.

Interfaces

```cs
public interface ILogin
{
   Task Login();
}
public interface IRegister
{
   Task Register();
}
```

and the UserService class;

```cs
public class UserService: IRegister, ILogin
{
   public Task Login()
   {
      //implementation logic here
   } 
   public Task Register()
   {
      //implementation logic here
   } 
}
```

the Login Controller client

```cs
public class LoginController : Controller
{
   private ILogin login;
   public Login Controller(ILogin login)
   {
      this.login = login;
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Login()
   {
      //implementation logic here for login.post
   } 
}
```

I would like to know if this implementation breaks any design principle or if it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Then you'll need to register both services with DI explicitly. `services.AddScoped<ILogin,User>(); ....`. However is `User` a service? or is it data?

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem is with your code. Looks like it should compile and work fine?

Comment: @zaitsman I know it would compile and work fine. My question is have I broken any design principle with this implementation or is it an antipattern?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman user is a service class.

Comment: @OlamideJon-Ajumobi I think you're overthinking it. Design principles make sense when you get to a 'code smell'. Like thousands of lines in a class. A method with tens of lines. That kind of stuff. With what you're doing it's a-okay, my issue would be with a naming convention you have. E.g. a `User` is an entity, a model. Not a `service`. So I would have a `IUserService` implemented by `UserService`. 

And if you want to really break down parts of your code look at CQRS (and/or Mediatr).

Comment: @zaitsman Userservice is a more befitting name. I would update my question

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe they should even be to different classes.

Comment: "does this break _any_ design principle" is way too broad a question, and an opinion-based one at that. Do you have an _actual_, _practical_ problem with this code? If not, then it's off-topic to ask about it here (consider another site like Code Review or Software Engineering for open-ended/opinion-based questions for improvement or review).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just one method from your service in Controller, then it is okay to use interface `ILogin`.

ISP is how interface can be consumed. It means don’t depend on more than you need. That is there is no need `LoginController` to consume the following methods like `Register()`.

ISP's goal is to hide unnecessary information. Why? To minimize coupling and dependency.

[Read more about ISP here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249832/interface-segregation-principle-program-to-an-interface)