# How to apply Interface segregation principle?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, interface

I have a public interface that creates a bunch of different specific objects by client, and the only thing in common is that they all need to be serialized as xmls.

Something like this:

```
public interface IBuildXmlService
{
    XmlObject1 BuildClient1Xml(CustomObjectWithClient1Data data);
    XmlObject2 BuildClient2Xml(CustomObjectWithClient2Data data);
    XmlObject3 BuildClient3Xml(string string1, int int1);
    XmlObject4 BuildClient4Xml(CustomObjectWithClient4Data data);
}
```

Now this interface started to get big, and I'm definitely sure this is not a good sign. Also every time I inject the interface into a client specific class, that client specific class has access to all the other object creation methods for other clients.

Now the first thing I thought about was to just move the object creation method as a private method in client specific class, but this results in quite some big files.

Then I thought to use the factory method pattern to create a IXmlFactory with a BuildXml method for the object creation part, but this doesn't seem to work since I have different objects to return.

Can anyone give me some advice about what design pattern should I look for?

Comment: does the signature of the methods for different clients are all different ? is there a way to redesign the so that they have a common signature ?

Comment: Not really, I'm using some xsd generated classes to create the objects that get serialized to an xml while sending them as a request to a SOAP Api. There are different xmls I need to generate based on different actions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a public interface that creates a bunch of **different specific** objects by client, and the **only thing in common is that they all need to be serialized** as xmls.

So it can be concluded that there is no common between these objects. Even parameters of these methods are different.

So my suggestion is to separate all methods and create separate interface for each object:

```
public interface IBuildXmlServiceXmlObject_1 
{
    XmlObject1 BuildClient1Xml(CustomObjectWithClient1Data data);
}

public interface IBuildXmlServiceXmlObject_2
{
    XmlObject2 BuildClient2Xml(CustomObjectWithClient2Data data);
}

public interface IBuildXmlServiceXmlObject_3 
{   
    XmlObject3 BuildClient3Xml(string string1, int int1);
}

public interface IBuildXmlServiceXmlObject_4 
{       
    XmlObject4 BuildClient4Xml(CustomObjectWithClient4Data data);
}
```

Why is it better to have separate interfaces? Because [Interface Segregation Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249832/interface-segregation-principle-program-to-an-interface) is how interface can be consumed. So, whether it is necessary to consume other methods of interface or don’t depend on more than you need.

An example with HDD that uses ISP:

```
public interface IReadable
{
    string Read();
}

public interface IWriteable
{
    void Write();
}

public class HDD : IReadable, IWriteable
{
    public string Read() { }

    public void Write()  { }
}
```

By creating one interface for `Read()` and `Write()` methods, it would obligate class to implement *both* methods in class. But some classes only want to read data, others want to write data, and some to do both. E.g. card reader might want to read data. So in this case it is better to create separate interfaces.

So let's look another example with *CardReader*. *CardReader* just reads data, it does not write data. So, if we inherit one interface with `Read()` and `Write()` methods, then we  would violate ISP principle. An example of violation of ISP:

```
public interface IWriteReadable
{
    string Read();
    void Write();
}

public class CardReader : IWriteReadable
{
    // this is a necessary method
    public string Read() { }

    // here we are obligating to implement unnecessary method of interface
    public void Write() { }
}
```

So by applying ISP, you only puts methods in interface that are necessary for the client class. If your class/client just wants to read data, then you need to use `IReadable` interface, not `IReadableWriteable`.

Comment: but since I don't expect the methods to be reused, why should they be in a public interface? They are specific for that client, and for that client only.

Comment: @test13  you can use any access modifier for interface based on your needs

Comment: @test13 Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)